# Change Fragment on ItemSelected In HeaderFragment Android leanback Activity

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I want to open profile fragment or activity when profile item selected. Can anyone tell me how I can do this in browsefragment

[image]

```
 HeaderItem gridHeader = new HeaderItem(2, "Profile");

    GridItemPresenter mGridPresenter = new GridItemPresenter();
    ArrayObjectAdapter gridRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(mGridPresenter);

    gridRowAdapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.view_profile));
    rowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(gridHeader, gridRowAdapter));
```

Comment: Please give more details on what you want to achieve.

Comment: i have to open frragemnt when i select any item in Headerfragment Like i have profile item when i select profile new fragment would be open . i am working in BrowsesupportFragment